# No primordial storage pool in windows 2012

Tags: storage, windows-server-2012

I recently installed Windows 2012 R2 Preview and are in need to construct a storage pool for usage with Thiered storage. And as the topic says there is no primordial storage pool in my system, this makes it impossible to set the rest up

Missing primordial
[image]

When trying to create a new pool
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder what is listed under disks?  Perhaps you haven't any dynamic volumes.

Comment: Actually no, I didn't have any mounted space that was unallocated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I hit the documentation and after a while reading I found out that the storage pool can (of course) only use disk space that is unallocated.

Hence, either create some unallocated space on your existing drives or create some VHD/VHDX via the disk manager and leave them unallocated.

Great!

Answer (score 0):

No nallocated space is normal solution.
Second problem can be physical disk size under 4 gigabytes. Under this size of HDD drive can not be pooled! This happends, if you try to play with too little VHDs :o)